# How to use a coroutine inside the Update in Unity to wait for seconds to rotate the camera? (C#)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, coroutine

This is part of my code:

```
void Update(){
CameraFlip();
}
void CameraFlip(){
        Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 180);
        cameraTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (cameraTransform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * 4.0f);
        Debug.Log (cameraTransform.rotation.ToString ());
        StartCoroutine("CameraFlipCoroutine");
    }

    public IEnumerator CameraFlipCoroutine(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (Random.Range(6f,12f));
        if (gameIsPlaying == false)
            yield return null;
        Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0);
        cameraTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (cameraTransform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * 4.0f);
        Debug.Log (cameraTransform.rotation.ToString ());
    }
```

So What I would like to do is to rotate the camera with 180 angles if something is happened in the update method. (For example, the player hit an enemy) And after a few seconds the camera turns back to its original position.

With my code the first part is OK, it turns as I wanted but then when the coroutine part comes, it starts turning but it's lagging and it is not smooth.

I don't know. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's lagging because you are calling it many times.On Update () you are calling the function CameraFlip() many times every second.

What you could do to see if that's the problem is creating an bool variable just like this:

```
private bool testingFlip = false;
```

Then you check it when you need it, for exemple:

```
void Update(){
    if (!testingFlip){`       
        CameraFlip();
        testingFlip = true;
    }
}
```

And in some point you make it false again to use it when you need it. It's not fancy, but it's a good way to test if that is what causing the lag.

Comment: This is not good because `cameraTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (cameraTransform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * 4.0f);` this code needs the multiple call to make it turn.